# Remove the row with a specific value from excel in javacode

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to remove all the rows from the excel having value 1 in column F and save it in a new excel in java code. My java code is below. New excel is getting created but I am unable to remove all the rows with value 1 in column F. My java code is:

```
final String filterValue = "1";
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream("Users.xls");
            System.out.println("File read successfully!!");

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            HSSFWorkbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook();
            wb2 = wb;

            Row row;
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            int getLastCell=row.getLastCellNum()-1;
            int lastIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
                row=sheet.getRow(i);
                if(row.getCell(getLastCell)!=null && (row.getCell(getLastCell).equals(filterValue)))
                          {
                            System.out.println("Removing row "+row);
                           sheet.removeRow(row);
                           //sheet.shiftRows(i, lastIndex, -1);
                        }

                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("FilteredUserList.xls");
                wb2.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
            }
```

Comment: `row.getCell(getLastCell).equals(filterValue)` checks if a `Cell` is equal to a `String`. you should use `cell.getStringCellValue().equals(filterValue)`

Comment: I changed it to :  Cell cell=row.getCell(getLastCell);
    if(cell!=null && (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(filterValue)))   but still get the same error

Comment: what error are you talking of?

Comment: Same error that reading numeric value from text cell. But using DataFormatter it is fixed. But the rows that were having value as 1 are now shown as blank in excel. They are not shifted up.

Comment: show stacktrace and full code